# SPA automatically take hidden input value and insert into param in query

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am creating a single page application. I am trying to select a table in sql and search a field for a certain date `Date_Due` then to make sure another field `Date_Complete` is null. I am trying to figure out how to have a hidden field fill in a cfparam in my query. My hidden field automatically has the correct date done because of JQuery but I need to know how to pass the form.value to the param since nothing is being submitted or inserted. Its just a hidden field with the correct date already that I need to some how automatically pass to the query inside of the param.

http://jsfiddle.net/byyeh83t/8/

The fiddle shows the input automatically receiving the date. But since nothing is being submitted no button press nothing how do I take the form.value and insert that into the param in my query?

```
<input name="TomorrowsDate" id="TomorrowsDate" type="hidden"/>

    <cfquery name="tomorrowTextArea">
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work
            WHERE Date_Due = <cfqueryparam value="form.TomorrowsDate" /> 
            AND Date_Complete IS NULL       
        </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeline for your webpage looks this way:

- GET - Request to load the html page **SERVER**
- Javascript/jQuery performs the calculation of the date **CLIENT**
- Javascript/jQuery sets the value of your hidden input **CLIENT**
- You require query results that depend on the calculated date **SERVER**

If you don't want to reload your page

> But since nothing is being submitted no button press nothing

some kind of an asynchronous message is required.

```
var dateForQuery = AddBusinessDays(dateMin, 1); 
$.ajax(
    'your_query_page.cfm',
    {data: {date: dateForQuery }}
).done(function(result){
    \\ do something with the query result
});
```

And on the server side:

```
<cfparam name="URL.date" default="#Now()#" />

<cfquery name="tomorrowTextArea">
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work
    WHERE Date_Due = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.date#" /> 
    AND Date_Complete IS NULL       
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(tomorrowTextArea)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the query results ... do you want to display them on the page?

Comment: Required Message; ColdFusion (the Server) does not know your Javascript variables, since they are client side. Therefore you have to communicate with the server. This is either done by reloading the page or some kind of asyncronous messaging.